# chemfig: align multiple reactions

Tags: chemfig

How can I align multiple reactions to the reaction arrow using `chemfig`?

In the MWE, I want to align the two reactions to the arrow.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{Cl}\chemsign+\chemfig{O_3}
\chemrel{->}
\chemfig{ClO}\chemsign+\chemfig{O_2}

\chemfig{ClO}\chemsign+\chemfig{O}
\chemrel{->}
\chemfig{Cl}\chemsign+\chemfig{O_2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Here's a `chemfig` only way: use its `\startscheme ... \stopscheme` mechanism in combination with the invisible »arrow« `0` and the anchoring of TikZ nodes.  The trick here:

  ```
  \arrow(@c1.south east--.north east){0}[-90,.1]
  ```

  an invisible arrow `{0}` pointing downwards (`-90`) and shortened (`.1`) that connects compound `c1` with a new one, the former anchored `south east` and the latter `north east`. You can see what `chemfig` treats as compounds if you add `\schemedebug{true}` before the scheme.

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{chemfig}
  \begin{document}
  \schemestart
    Cl \+ \printatom{O_3} \arrow ClO \+ \printatom{O_2}
    \arrow(@c1.south east--.north east){0}[-90,.1]
    ClO \+ O \arrow Cl \+ \printatom{O_2}
  \schemestop
  \end{document}
  ```

  [image]
- As you've noted [in your own answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193472/5049) `chemfig` can also be used in combination with `amsmath`'s alignment environments, similar to the following proposals
- Simple reactions like the ones shown in the question can also be typeset with `mhchem` and `amsmath`:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{mhchem}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
    \cee{Cl + O3 &-> ClO + O2} \\
    \cee{ClO + O &-> Cl + O2}
  \end{align*}
  \end{document}
  ```

  [image]
- Another possibility would be `chemformula` with `amsmath` oder `chemmacros`:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[ghsystem=false]{chemmacros}% loads amsmath and chemformula
  \begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
    \ch{Cl + O3 &-> ClO + O2} \\
    \ch{ClO + O &-> Cl + O2}
  \end{align*}
  \begin{reactions*}
    Cl + O3 &-> ClO + O2 \\
    ClO + O &-> Cl + O2
  \end{reactions*}
  \end{document}
  ```

  [image]

Comment: The last approach is what I was after for, thank you! A bit of a hax, but does the trick.

Comment: I believe that the `0` arrow is there for such purposes. I often find it very useful!

Answer (score 1):

`chemfig` can be used inside `align` environment. Thus, it can be done as

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\chemfig{Cl}\chemsign+\chemfig{O_3}
& \chemrel{->}
\chemfig{ClO}\chemsign+\chemfig{O_2} \\
\chemfig{ClO}\chemsign+\chemfig{O}
& \chemrel{->}
\chemfig{Cl}\chemsign+\chemfig{O_2}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The downside of this answer is that the reactions are inside `align` and not `chemfig`. For example, you cannot scale the equations easily.